# RecyclerView item view updates after scrolling up or down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView and list of items. Items are observed in viewModel, adapter gets a changed list whenever list in viewModel changes.

However, I have a problem when updating certain item views in existing list item - these changes happen, but to see them I have to scroll up or down a bit. In view holder I have all necessary if/else cases what to update according to item values. Is there a way to update item view instantly, without having to scroll?

Comment: views are recycled. so only few items at a time are displayed. when you scroll you see the update casue the data in binded to your views again based on the position

Answer (score 0):

You can call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` function to force the adapter to redraw all items again.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(int indexOfChangedItem)` or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you changing any item of the list.

the first one will update 'all' item viewes but the second one will update only the view that you passed it's index.